# Select article AND select article liked time only if article liked (if there is row with userID in Article likes)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 simple tables

**first table**

```
Articles
================
ID
Title
Content
```

**and the second table**

```
Article_Likes
================
ArticleID (FK)
UserID
Time
```

I want to select Article Title, content AND Liked Time ONLY if the user liked the article (if there is a row in Article_Likes table)

This is my code, it returns article and liked time OK. But if there is no row in Article_Likes (he not liked), I get empty result.

**How to select Article even if he not liked. But if he liked, select liked time too?**
please, help. Thank you

```
SELECT
   Article.ID,
   Article.Title,                                       
   Article.Content,
   Article_Likes.Time
FROM Articles
   INNER JOIN Article_Likes ON Articles.ID = Article_Likes.PostID
WHERE  Article.ID = (ArticleID)
   AND Article_Likes.UserID = (UserID)
LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT** This query works please check the syntacsis

```
SELECT  Article.ID, 
    Article.Title, 
    Article.Content, 
    COALESCE(Article_Likes.Time,'NOT LIKED') AS Time
FROM Articles
    LEFT JOIN Article_Likes ON Article.ID = Article_Likes.ArticleID AND Article_Likes.UserID = (UserID)
WHERE Article.ID = (ArticleID)
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
   Article.ID,
   Article.Title,                                       
   Article.Content,
   COALESCE(Article_Likes.Time,'NOT LIKED') AS Time
FROM Articles
   LEFT JOIN Article_Likes ON Article.ID = Article_Likes.ArticleID 
WHERE  Article.ID = (ArticleID)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, for response, but i get empty result, can u suggest anything?

Comment: @user3395525: If you are not getting what you are looking for with this query, I suggest you to show some sample data of all the tables including `Posts` and `Post_Likes`.

Comment: Sorry for waiting. I wrote new query in question. It combined from yours and @AK47's answer. It works, anyway please check syntacsis. is it correct? Thank you

Comment: @user3395525: Don't you want to join the `post` table as well?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I mistake when I changed code for SO. I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

Insted of inner, use left join. As inner join shows values which exists in both table, whenever you want all records from table on left (Articles) use LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT
   Article.ID,
   Article.Title,                                       
   Article.Content,
   Article_Likes.Time
FROM Articles
   LEFT JOIN Article_Likes ON Posts.ID = Post_Likes.PostID
              AND Post_Likes.UserID = (UserID)
WHERE  Article.ID = (ArticleID)
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i get empty result anyway.

Comment: Sorry, for incorrect ans, now I have edited my ans. Please check. There should not any condition in where clause containing column from Right table. In your case it was there (AND Post_Likes.USE....)

Comment: Sorry for waiting. I wrote new query in question. It combined from yours and @Raging Bull's answer. It works, anyway please check syntacsis. is it correct? Thank you